# Generics: What's a "CONSTRUCTOR constraint"?

Tags: delphi, generics, constructor, delphi-2009

I made a custom TObjectList descendant designed to hold subclasses of a base object class.  It looks something like this:

```
interface
   TMyDataList<T: TBaseDatafile> = class(TObjectList<TBaseDatafile>)
   public
      constructor Create;
      procedure upload(db: TDataSet);
   end;

implementation

constructor TMyDataList<T>.Create;
begin
   inherited Create(true);
   self.Add(T.Create);
end;
```

I want each new list to start out with one blank object in it.  It's pretty simple, right?  But the compiler doesn't like it.  It says:

"Can't create new instance without CONSTRUCTOR constraint in type parameter declaration"
I can only assume this is something generics-related.  Anyone have any idea what's going on and how I can make this constructor work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of `T` via `T.Create`. This doesn't work because the compiler doesn't know that your generic type has a parameterless constructor (remember: this is no requirement). To rectify this, you've got to create a constructor constraint, which looks like this:

```
<T: constructor>
```

or, in your specific case:

```
<T: TBaseDatafile, constructor>
```

Comment: Bah.  In this case, the compiler *does* know that TBaseDataFile has a virtual constructor that takes no parameters.

Comment: @Mason: I can't speak for Delphi, and in general you're right that the compiler *could* know if it just looked at the right place. However, this is just not how it works, in order to to make the code more explicit.
C++ is another story: it doesn't require such constraints in comparable cases.

Comment: @Konrad: Exactly, a good compiler such as FPC 3.1.1 does not need such constraints, this works fine there. Apparently Delphi compiler is not good, and that's one of the reasons why it is, well almost, dead.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick update to an old question..

You don't need the constructor constraint and can also do this on object's with parameters by using RTTI like this (using RTTI or System.RTTI with XE2)

```
constructor TMyDataList<T>.Create;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
   inherited Create(true);
   self.Add(
     ctx.
     GetType(TClass(T)).
     GetMethod('create').
     Invoke(TClass(T),[]).AsType<T>
   );
end;
```

If you have parameters, just add them like this

```
constructor TMyDataList<T>.Create;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
   inherited Create(true);
   self.Add(
     ctx.
     GetType(TClass(T)).
     GetMethod('create').
     Invoke(TClass(T),[TValue.From('Test'),TValue.From(42)]).AsType<T>
   );
end;
```

Comment: In fact it's easiest to write `TBaseDatafile(T).Create`