# What is the use case for the constructor constraint in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, parameterized-types

The title is pretty much it...

Why would you ever want to use the `constructor` constraint?

It's clearly implied by the `class` constraint.

If you use it alone, you can't do anything with the thing you've created.

Why does it even exist?

**Additional info:**

Just as a note, the following code doesn't compile until you add the "constructor" constraint:

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;


type
  TSomeClass<T: class> = class
    function GetType: T;
  end;


{ TSomeClass<T> }

function TSomeClass<T>.GetType: T;
begin
  Result := T.Create;
end;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Related, [Generics: What's a “CONSTRUCTOR constraint”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383689/576719).

Comment: It's pretty much useless because it has to be parameterless.

Comment: After the above added code, it seems to me that the class constraint should imply the constructor constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why would you ever want to use the constructor constraint?
>
> It's clearly implied by the class constraint.

No it's not. The constructor constraint requires that the type has a public, parameterless constructor - and then allows that constructor to be called.

Not all classes have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: But why would you care?  (and I must say it is an honor to have my question answered by the immortal Jon Skeet!)

Comment: @NickHodges If type has constructor constraint then e.g. you can write T.Create.

Comment: @Linas -- Yeah, I know.  I'm just wondering why you'd care.  I'm guessing it might be for the purposes of a Factory or something like that, but I'm just wondering what the "official" reason is.

Comment: @NickHodges: You'd care precisely *because* in factory cases etc you may well want to create a new instance. You care because it allows you to do something which you otherwise can't do.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please give an simple example of a class not having a public parameterless constructor, that cannot be used with a generic class TFoo<T:class, constructor>?

Comment: The interesting thing though is that the class constraint in C# does NOT only mean it has to be a class but a reference type! And a reference type does not always have a parameterless contructor (interface for example). But in Delphi the class constructor is basically equal to a TObject constraint (which does not exist). Clearly someone at Embarcadero missed that point as so often when copying stuff from C#/.Net.

Comment: @NickHodges as a conclusion from Stefans comment and my research (see my updated answer), this answer is wrong

Comment: @StefanGlienke: You don't need to go to interfaces to get that though - even if the class constraint really did limit it to classes, there are plenty of classes which don't have public parameterless constructors. (`FileStream`, for example.) I confess I don't know much about Delphi, but can you really not create a class which doesn't have a public parameterless constructor? There are plenty of types where that really doesn't make sense IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you know the trick of how to hide the default constructor from TObject (http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2011/07/hiding-the-tobject-create-constructor/) then it makes sense, yes. Otherwise you always have access to that one.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: Ick. I think I'd need to know more Delphi to understand why the language was designed that way. Being able to create instances of arbitrary types without going through normal validation of "this actually makes sense" doesn't sound good to me :(

Comment: @JonSkeet As you can see in my comment to Sir Rufos answer it actually can break things. You have to keep in mind that generics in Delphi are a rather new language feature and were not part of the initial design. And often new things are rather sloppy copy jobs from C# without knowing the details (like the class constraint) or considering the differences between C# and Delphi (IEnumerable)

Comment: @StefanGlienke: So is my answer here actually accurate? I definitely don't want to leave incorrect information around... if you have any suggested changes, feel free to edit...

Comment: @JonSkeet I think it is accurate however requires knowledge about the facts that: by default every class has a public default constructor (the TObject one) and more importantly: you can only hide it from the compiler by using the trick I posted the link to earlier (introducing a non overloaded version with parameters does NOT do the job). And now when thinking about that I think this definetly is a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the official reason for that constraint is that the compiler can't handle it actually by himself.

It is just a flag for the compiler which can also be set by himself, because the compiler does recognizes the fact, that we need a constructor constraint. So it could be handled automatically by the compiler, because the Generic class will be compiled before using that class.

Maybe we will get it with XE9

UPDATE

If TComponent is accepted as a class type without a public parameterless constructor then the constructor constraint is useless, because this (extended sample from Nick) compiles and produces a TComponent Instance. Of course it will not call the original constructor TComponent.Create( AOwner : TComponent ), instead TObject.Create is called, but you have a TComponent Instance.

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

type
  TSomeClass<T: class, constructor> = class
    function GetType: T;
  end;

{ TSomeClass<T> }

function TSomeClass<T>.GetType: T;
begin
  Result := T.Create;
end;

var
  SomeClass : TSomeClass<TComponent>;
  Component : TComponent;
begin
  try
    SomeClass := TSomeClass<TComponent>.Create;
    Component := SomeClass.GetType;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

UPDATE

```
TSomeClass<T: class, constructor>
```

has the same meaning as

```
TSomeClass<T: constructor>
```

because a record can have a constructor, but not a parameterless, so we have an implicit constraint to a class. And turning this around

```
TSomeClass<T: class>
```

could have an implicit constructor constraint

Comment: In fact you can end up with only partly or non initialized instances that way. Try creating a control that way for example. While you cannot call TControl.Create because it is hidden by the constructor that takes AOwner the compiler can when given to a generic type with constructor constraint!